# Using ArcMap to build a Terrain DEM that looks exactly the same as a TIN built from the same point shapefile

Tags: arcmap, terrain, tin

I am attempting to replicate DEMs previously constructed as TINs in the Terrain format. Building a Terrain and a TIN out of the same point shapefile produces two maps that look extremely similar, but when I run the results through the Surface Volume the Terrain and TIN give slightly different volume results. The volume of the Terrain also changes depending on whether Z Tolerance or Window Size is used as a pyramiding method even though the Surface Volume tool is analyzing the full resolution Terrain data. Is there a specific set of parameters that will produce a Terrain that gives identical volume results to a TIN or are the two methods inherently different in some way?